# Function not being executed from within another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm writing a tool that shall monitor delivery of shipments to pickup locations.
This is based on UPS API and soon DHL.
I retrieve the resultset from MS SQL database - airwaybill references and want to check with UPS API whether they have certain status : 'This package is being held for a future delivery date. / Delivery will be rescheduled.'
Then i return JSON object with delivery date and time to later store back in the DB.

I wrote to functions :
- one for retrieving AWBs from DB
- one to retrieve results from UPS

problem is that i cannot nest them - UPS one is not being called (ignored with no error) from the other.

```
import {upstrack} from './ups';
import {get} from './sql';

get(function(result) { 
    result.forEach(function (data) {
        console.log(data.AWB) // it outputs the AWB numbers to the console correctly
        upstrack(data.AWB) // this is not even executed - no error pops in the console
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    })
})

upstrack('1Z17704F0470475280') //calling this from the root of file will result with the answer being output to the console
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Any ideas how to call the upstrack(awb) function to get the result ?

ups.js file:

```
var Tracking = require('./lib/tracking');
var tracking = new Tracking('myhash', 'mylogin', 'mypass');

let upstrack = (awb) => {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      tracking.setJsonResponse(true);
      tracking.useSandbox(false); 
      tracking.makeRequest({
        customerContext: "Customer Data", trackingNumber : awb
      }, function(data, err) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err) 
        }
        if (data) {
          var results = data.TrackResponse.Shipment[0].Package[0].Activity
          var AWB = data.TrackResponse.Shipment[0].ShipmentIdentificationNumber[0]
          results.forEach(element => {
              if (element.Status[0].StatusType[0].Description[0] == 'This package is being held for a future delivery date. / Delivery will be rescheduled.')
                {
                var response = []
                response.push({
                  awb: AWB,
                  status: element.Status[0].StatusType[0].Description[0],
                  date: element.Date[0].replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1-$2-$3'),
                  time: element.Time[0].replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1:$2:$3')
                })
                resolve(response)
              }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  )
}

export { upstrack }
```

Comment: Shot in the dark: `result.AWB` should be `data.AWB`. But you should provide more data and code, otherwise nobody will be able to help.

Comment: what @str said, it looks like you may be passing an `undefined` value into that "upstrack" function but hard to tell without seeing implementation upstrack as well as what the result object looks like

Comment: You only `resolve` when two conditions are met. Probably one of them is not met. But again, there is no way to help without data.

Comment: calling upstrack(awb) function from root and not from within get() provides result

Answer (score 0):

You are not guaranteed to `resolve` here, nor are you guaranteed to `resolve` only once with the same resolution. You should resolve in an `else` when your `if(data)` is false-y, and you should not `resolve` in a loop, especially when you are still potentially building an array (which isn't actually happening because `response` is scoped).

If you are not familiar with Array iteration functions I would highly recommend you learn them. They can really help clean up your code and help you accomplish a lot more easily. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype

```
var Tracking = require("./lib/tracking");
var tracking = new Tracking("myhash", "mylogin", "mypass");

let upstrack = awb => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        tracking.setJsonResponse(true);
        tracking.useSandbox(false);
        tracking.makeRequest({
                customerContext: "Customer Data",
                trackingNumber: awb
            },
            function(data, err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                if (data) {
                    var results = data.TrackResponse.Shipment[0].Package[0].Activity;
                    var AWB = data.TrackResponse.Shipment[0].ShipmentIdentificationNumber[0];
                    resolve(
                        results
                        .filter(
                            element =>
                            element.Status[0].StatusType[0].Description[0] ==
                            "This package is being held for a future delivery date. / Delivery will be rescheduled."
                        )
                        .map(element => ({
                            awb: AWB,
                            status: element.Status[0].StatusType[0].Description[0],
                            date: element.Date[0].replace(
                                /(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g,
                                "$1-$2-$3"
                            ),
                            time: element.Time[0].replace(
                                /(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/g,
                                "$1:$2:$3"
                            )
                        }))
                    );
                } else {
                    resolve([]);
                }
            }
        );
    });
};

export {
    upstrack
};
```

Add logs before and after:

```
    console.log(data.AWB) // it outputs the AWB numbers to the console correctly
    upstrack(data.AWB) // this is executed but since the promise never resolves...
    .then(response => console.log(response)) // ...this never logs...
    .catch(error => console.log(error)); // ...and this never logs
    console.log(data.AWB) // it outputs the AWB numbers to the console
```

Comment: thank you really much for your effort - you are most likely right, however not addressing my problem which is being unable to exec upstrack() function from within get()

where as it runs correctly from the root of file

Comment: my understanding is that your `then`/`catch` are not being called, but if you log before `upstrack(data.AWB) ` and after `upstrack(data.AWB) ` then you will see both logs (see updated answer for more clarity), the problem seems to be that the promise is not being resolved. The code provided ensures the promise is resolved once in all cases. Maybe there are some essential details missing?

Comment: Why is the promise being resolved when function called not within other function then ?

Comment: Have you tried executing `upstrack("1Z17704F0470475280")` inside the `get`? Does your then or catch get called then? How about inside the `forEach`?

Comment: doesn't run / no errors anywhere inside get() {}

if run from the root runs correctly

Comment: can it be some context : this undefined issue ?

`console.log('this: ', this, ', arguments: ', arguments);`
run from within get() returns:
this:  undefined , arguments:  [Arguments] {}

but run from the root returns this : {}

Comment: At this point I don't think I can help you without debugging the whole app myself, the provided code should have resolved the issue imo, unless `tracking.makeRequest` is written incorrectly, have you tried `const upstrack = () => Promise.resolve(arguments)`, instead of importing it, this will at least tell you if you are provided the same args in both cases

Comment: problem was context this undefined

after i changed trackups function to return promise instead of callback it worked